# What does | operator mean in expression-bodied property?

Tags: c#, operators

What does | operator mean in statement looking like that:

```
public int IntProperty => (booTrue ? 1 : 0) | (fooTrue ? 2 : 0);
```

I'm familiar with => and ? but I've never seen | used like that.

Comment: "Bitwise or", basically

Comment: | (bitwise OR) Takes two numbers as operands and does OR on every bit of two numbers. The result of OR is 1 any of the two bits is 1.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the expression-bodied property, it is simple C# 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s a [bitwise or](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-or-operator-). If we look at the values in your code you could have:

- 0 => `00`
- 1 => `01`
- 2 => `10`

So, if `booTrue` is true and `fooTrue` is true, it will be `1 | 2`. As it's a bitwise or, it will be `01 | 10` => `11` in decimal => 3 .

Comment: Much thanks! Seems to me like complicated way of writing things though. At least in this example.

Comment: @Speedo It's a "clever" way of writing `fooTrue ? (booTrue ? 3 : 2) : (booTrue ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: Yeah but that seems to me like it only works in this exact example by total accident. What if had numbers like 5, 11, 17 not 1, 2, 3, what if those where objects or arrays. It almost like whoever wrote that wanted to show off himself what of a l33t programmer he is. What is actual benefit of writing it like that? but that outside of the topic, thanks tho.